# change href state in other files

Tags: href, state

3 Files:
a.php, b.php and c.php;

In a.php there are the following hrefs

```
<a href="b.php">The b tag</a>
<a href="c.php">The c tag</a>
```

In b.php there are the following hrefs

```
<a href="a.php">The a tag</a>
<a href="c.php">The c tag</a>
```

In c.php there are the following hrefs

```
<a href="a.php">The a tag</a>
<a href="b.php">The b tag</a>
```

If the b and c hrefs in a.php are clicked, how can the b and c tags in the files b.php and c.php be show as clicked when these files are viewed?

Have tried putting all the files in one file and then calling the individual files using if statements have also tried include statements - these do not work. Looks like a javascript onclick solution.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

in css add

```
a:visited{ color : red; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: none;} // EDIT THE CSS VALUES YOU WANT
```